# Load more data on scroll if DOM contains height-changing divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got this piece of AJAX code

```
        $(window).on('scroll', function(e) { 
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:'includes/fetch_home_posts_2.php',
              data:{ 'offset':flag, 'limit':5},
              success:function(data){
                $('#fetched_home_posts').append(data);
                flag += 5;
              }
            });
          }
        });
```

When user loads the page, he sees first 5 posts.
The posts look like this:
[screenshot of a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYH0.png)

Then thanks to this AJAX code he loads more posts on scroll (works fine).

The problem is, that when user clicks the "Comments" button, the div expands, changes its height and when user hits bottom of the page, no more posts are loaded (even though there are more to be loaded).

[screenshot of expanded post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDVac.png)

How can this situation be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake. I has several `"flag" vars` in different `<script></script>` tags. I just renamed them to `"post_flag"`, `"comment_flag"` etc. and it is working now.